# Accidently lost /home during shrinking process with resize2fs

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, lvm, resize

I tried to decrease size of my `/home` in order to increase my root `/` which is too small. I tried to achieve this by following this [walkthrough](https://pingtool.org/online-resize-lvm-partitions-shrink-home-extend-root/?unapproved=39065&moderation-hash=68684e835375646de01d336115648ebb#comment-39065). Unfortunately, I wasn't aware of the differences between standard partitions (which  my system is based on) and the logical volume management (LVM; which the walkthrough is based on)...at least that's what I suppose.

In brief what I did:

1.Login as root

2.Unmount my `/home` via

```
umount /home
```

3.Shrink my /home partition from 436G by 10G to 426G

```
e2fsck -f /dev/my_home
resize2fs /dev/my_home 426G
```

4.Try to reduce /home to 426G

```
lvreduce -L 426G /dev/my_home
```

Here I get the error that the location `/dev/my_home` does not exists. Indeed, checking via

```
df -h
```

does not show my `/home` anymore.

I'm pretty much stuck here and have the strong fear that I have somehow destroyed my `/home` partition with the `resize2fs` command. I'm still actively in the session, since I don't dare to reboot. Help is very much appreciated!

System: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: no unfortunately not

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to have been destructive at the end. Still, I don't understand why `lvreduce` couldn't locate my `/home` any more. In any case, I would advice other amateur Linux users (like me) to use `gparted` for resizing partitions. At least for me, it seems much safer.

Comment: OK so I misread your original question - I thought you had used instructions applicable for a traditional partitioned system when your system was LVM based. I now see it was the other way around - in which case, it should be no surprise that neither `lvreduce` nor the other lvm-based tools work

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, rereading my question I admit that it's not entirely clear the way I formulated it (sorry I'm not a native English speaker). I edit my question to avoid the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I managed to resize my partitions without any (obvious) data loss. For the sake of potential future lost souls (like me), I quickly drop the solution to my problem:

With my /home being unmounted I first resized it to its original size via

```
resize2fs /dev/my_home
```

This basically expands `/dev/my_home` into the non-allocated space.
In my case the system required me to run first

```
e2fsck -f /dev/my_home
```

which I did, confirming to optimize my system when asked.

Then I restarted from live USB, opened Gparted, and moved/resized the partitions accordingly. I then rebooted into a normal session. From what I can tell, the partitions have been correctly resized + I can access all my data. Phew!

Note: Since I had to move my /home with gparted I expected to reinstall GRUB. But in my case it didn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Next time, don't go through such a hassle for the sake of a mere 10GB. Do at least 20. Really.

Answer (score 0):

`df -h` shows the available space on the *mounted* file systems only. So it would be normal not to see a partition you unmounted in order to resize it.

List your available partitions with the command

```
lsblk -fs
```

You can see the current devicename and UUID of the partitions. Both can be used to refer to the devices to mount the partition, e.g.

```
sudo mount UUID="<UUID>" /tmp
```

to mount the file system to the directory `/tmp`.

If the UUID of your /home partition has not been changed during the resize operation, it will automatically be mounted again on the next boot. Else, you will need to update the UUID in your `/etc/fstab` configuration file with the new UUID of the partition.